# Getting factor analysis scores when using the factanal function

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I have used the `factanal` function in R to do a factor analysis on a data set.

Viewing the summary of the output, I see I have access to the loading and other objects, but I am interested in the scores of the factor analysis.

How can I get the scores when using the `factanal` function?

I attempted to calculate the scores myself:

```
m <- t(as.matrix(factor$loadings))
n <- (as.matrix(dataset))
scores <- m%*%n
```

and got the error:

`Error in m %*% n : non-conformable arrays`

which I'm not sure why, since I double checked the dimension of the data and the dimensionality is in agreement.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Ah.

```
factormodel$loadings[,1] %*% t(dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a bit dated, but nevertheless:
`factanal` returns a matrix of scores. You simply call it like you called the loadings: `factor$scores`. No need to calculate it yourself. But you do need to specify in the function that you want to produce the scores, by using the "scores" argument.

Your solution, of multiplying the loadings by the observation matrix, is wrong. According to the FA model, the observed dataset should be the multiplication of loadings and scores (plus the unique contributions, and then rotation). This is not equivalent to what you wrote. I think you treated the loadings as the coefficients from observed data to scores, rather than the other way around (from scores to observations).

I found [this paper](https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1226&context=pare) that explains about different ways to extract scores, might be useful.